# BIRT reports temporary files growing inside instantly in GBs tomcats birt-viewer/documents

Tags: tomcat, birt

We get our servers' hard disk filled by tomcats birt-viewer temporary files. It ll instantly fill GBs unbelievably(10GB-100GBs) and tomcat gets struck. Need to always delete files inside the tomcat/webapp/birt-viewer/documents.

Answer (score 0):

- What BIRT version are you using?
- What kind of files / folders are left in the temp directory?

There were some issues with temp files in older BIRT versions, but they should be fixed as of version 4.2.2: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401068